# MySQL performance, should this take hours?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running the following query in MySQL Workbench:

```
UPDATE directorylistings INNER JOIN postcodelatlng ON PostalCode = postcode
set directoryListings.Latitude = postcodelatlng.latitude, directoryListings.Longitude = postcodelatlng.longitude
WHERE PostalCode = postcode;
```

Table directorylistings has 9000 records, postcodelatlng has nearly 2 million records.

directorylistings has a postcode (zip code) field and I'm looking this up in postcodelatlng to retrieve and update the latitude and longitude fields in directorylistings.

Ater timeout issues I found I should change DBMS connection read time out, I set this to 36000 (10 hours). The query has been running of 5 hours so far.

**My question is, is this time reasonable? Should I be indexing something? Could the query be optimised?**

I did make a 2 record version of the postcodelatlng and ran the query, 16 rows were correctly changed in 0.04 seconds, so I know the query is at least workable.

I have looked at a number of Q/A's on indexing and optimising, but it's taken me over a day to get this far and if it fails again I would like to know what approach to follow. I can't keep trying things and waiting hours for the failure! I bet this query should really take seconds. I'm using a MacBook Pro with a 2.5GHz i7, 16 GB RAM and ssd drive.

Many Thanks.

cpu is at 99%. I aborted after 12 hours! to run the show create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodelatlng` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1734490 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `directorylistings` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag11` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Minyan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `AffiliatedDate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `RegisteredDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShowListing` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bloguser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trusted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassifiedUser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HostingID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndPromoDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `BaseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Banner` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrivateListing` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved3` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved4` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CommunityOrg` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag3` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag4` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag6` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag7` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag8` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag9` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag10` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag12` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag13` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tag14` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShomerShabbos` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryID6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HiddenCategory` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Slogan` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CharShown` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unit` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Streetno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Building` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Locality` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Province` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ext` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber2` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FaxNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CellNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebUrl` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Keywords` varchar(355) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dcount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicantName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicantPhone` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicantEmail` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Photo1` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pRating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sRating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vRating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `VeryPrivate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SemiSecure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Secure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Secret` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TrustHigh` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FL` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `GJ` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Recommended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NonGeo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Edited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Editor` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: The time isn't reasonable, it should be much faster. You should be indexing `PostalCode` and `postcode`. The query looks fine. What's missing is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for both tables, so we can see if there's something obvious missing. Also, since you're on Mac, use standard tools (`top`, `Activity Monitor`) to check what's happening with MySQL process - is it utilizing a lot of CPU or disk. After that, post your findings here.

Comment: I have a feeling you've indexed the wrong things, if you have indexes at all. You need to edit and post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of these.

Comment: You're joining twice but that should be removed by the optimiser. Consider posting the EXPLAIN plan: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: @N.B. index over `directorylistings.PostalCode` would be redundant for this query.

Comment: @Denis create an index for `postcodelatlng.postcode` and you're good.

Comment: Why is `postcodelatlng.postcode` a `varchar(8)` and `directorylistings.PostalCode` a `varchar(10)`?

Comment: @Supersnake The postcodelatlng is a table with the postcode lookups I found and imported for this one off query.

Comment: Thanks all, I aborted after 12 hours since @N.B. was clear it shouldn't take so long. I indexed both tables postcode fields (seems the one would have done) and reran the query. It took a whopping 3.145 seconds to complete!!

Comment: How do I mark and answer as accepted? I read I'm supposed to click the check mark alongside it, but I don't see any.

Comment: There were no answers given - only comments.